# Position of gwt Buttons

Tags: java, gwt

I need to make a gui with gwt and have some question about positioning. How can I position gwt `Button` and `ListBox` on the gui panel? I have done simple position of labels with

```
html div style=position left:50px
```

but can't understand how to make it for buttons. Can anyone please help me?

sanpahot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GWT with CSS the same way as you use HTML with CSS. Define your CSS rules and apply CSS classes to your GWT widgets.

You can read more about styling GWT:

[Styling Existing Widgets](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html)

Answer (score 0):

> You are using **GWT** that provides a rich set of build in **[Widgets](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefWidgetGallery.html)** and **[Panels/Layouts](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html)** in its user-interface library.

You don't need to provide any absolute positioning at all.

Simply use a proper layout that fits as per your need and add the widgets in it that is automatically positioned and sized based on layout manager policy.

For more detail please visit [GWT Showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html)

Comment: for example for this layout in picture, wich panels can i use to position those elements!Like: to verticalPanel add the widget the button, and then to horizontalPanel add verticalPanel and after add it all to RootPanel?

Comment: You can try with multiple layouts in combination. you can insert a layout in different layout. Try with `DockLayoutPanel`, `Grid`, `FlexTable`, `FormPanel` etc.